# How to repeat the first letter twice using a str?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7

My goal is for the user to give the program a word; When done I want it to repeat the first letter twice using a str.

This is what I have so far:

```
phrase = input("Enter a word: ")

print (phrase[0])
```

---

Example for what I want the output to be like:

```
Enter a word: Hello
HH

Enter a word: Grey 
GG

Enter a word: Olives
OO
```

Comment: `print (phrase[0] * 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
phrase = input("Enter a word: ")

print (phrase[0]+phrase[0])
```

In general, adding two strings will concatenate them.